# How to create clickable row in table using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap to make the rows clickable but all I found is about lists. Is any way to do this?

I wrote this:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
        <td><strong>LastName</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
        <td><strong>End</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><a href="user/student">
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>                            
      </a></tr>
</table>
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: The question itself has nothing to do neither with js nor Bootstrap - it is a basic HTML question.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply attach an `onclick` event like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr onclick="window.location.href = 'url';">>
        <td><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
        <td><strong>LastName</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
        <td><strong>End</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="window.location.href = 'url';">
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>                            
      </a></tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to use jQuery as bootstrap also uses jQuery.

Comment: cause I want to move to another page by clicking any row.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put anchor in nested tr. It's not a proper use. Instead, use the

```
onclick="getElementById('edit-1').click()"
```

and add

`style="cursor: pointer"`

```
<table class="table table-hover">
 <tr>
    <td><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
    <td><strong>LastName</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
    <td><strong>End</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getElementById('edit-1').click()" style="cursor: pointer">
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td><a href="url-here" id="edit-1">dddd</a></td>                            
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add a function all tr same time;

```
 $("tr").click(function(){
     // your click time codes...
 });
```

table-hover class only add to rows color change property. not click function definition!

Comment: ...adding a `data-href` to `<tr>` where you'll store target URL to pass to `window.location.href` (for example).

Comment: I know, but it much complex to change the page that way. Im sure there is any functionality with bootstrap to do this.

Comment: You can use bootstrap for styling your page. Bootstrap include some css files. These class can set styles your page elements and help you to find them when you need to define functions by jquery

Comment: @yehonatan no, there is not (AFAIK). Will "use Bootstrap" replace old-fashioned "use jQuery"? LO

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to navigate to another page. If you are planning to go to another page as you said in the comments, you might want to use location.href = url. the first solution will work if you click on any row.

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
        <td><strong>LastName</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
        <td><strong>End</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><a>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>                            
      </a></tr>
</table>

$("row").click(function(){
    //to navigate to another page
    location.href = 'user/student';//the other page's url
 });
```

Another way to implement this is by using the onclick in the specific row. This solution will work if you click on the specific row that has the onclick.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
          <tr onclick="location.href='user/student';">
            <td><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
            <td><strong>LastName</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
            <td><strong>End</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><a>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td>ddd</td>                            
          </a></tr>
    </table>
```

Another way is to give an id to the row and use js or jquery to select that id and navigate to the page you want like below:

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
          <tr id="row1">
            <td><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
            <td><strong>LastName</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
            <td><strong>End</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><a>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td>ddd</td>                            
          </a></tr>
    </table>
    //now you can use this to navigate

$('#row1').on('click', function(){
     window.location = "user/student";    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved so: 
1 - put ID in your table:

> "tbListaFiadores"

2 - configure your table with :

> clickToSelect: true,

3 - get click event :

> $('#tbListaFiadores').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row,
>   $element) {
>   console.log("onClickRow normal");
>   });

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I see is to use [**jasny bootstrap component**](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink)

1. Import the .js file into your project
2. Put on tbody:

   ```
    <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink hand-cursor">
   ```
3. Put an **a** element on first **td** element

   ```
    <a href="#path"> path </a>
   ```
4. Now the link is already working. To make it rich use this css file and  its classes:

**CSS**

```
.hand-cursor { 
cursor: pointer; 
cursor: hand; 
}

.table-hoverplus>tbody>tr:hover>td {
 background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```